# Installing my Flutter app on an iPhone using Xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter

I am following [this](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-test-your-flutter-ios-app-on-your-ios-device-75924bfd75a8) tutorial to install a Flutter app on an iPhone.

I have never used Xcode before I am having some trouble finding stuff like "the Signing configuration" and how I can create and add teams to Xcode.

Here are my questions:

1. Do I need to pay for
   an Apple Developer account to be able to install an app using Xcode onto an iPhone? (Not concerned about publishing on the App Store for now).
2. Where do I find the "the Signing configuration"?
3. What is the deal with this "Personal team" thing that the tutorial talks about? Do I need one to be able to install an app on an iPhone from Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's free for develop, but for publishing to App Store you need to pay. Here you can register https://developer.apple.com/
2. [image: Signing settings]

3. You just need to fill Signings & Capabilities settings to be able install application on device. Please note, that you need to trust developer after installation in **Settings** -> **General** -> **Device Management** -> **Your Developer**